# Can creepage distance be separated into more sections?

Tags: isolation, distance, creepage

Can I count that the creepage distance of two separate circuits can be divided into two sections, while the inner conductive pad/track is isolated/floating?
Similarly, can I use two resistors (200V rating, 2mm creepage) in series to achieve the same as 400V rating and 4mm creepage resistor?

[image: example]

Comment: Yes you can do this.

Comment: If the central 'isolated' pad is truly symmetrically isolated, yes, you can do this. There is a technique in high voltage switching whereby two spark gaps in series are made assymetrical by a high value resistor across one of them. The resulting combo breaks down at the voltage of one spark gap only. It will be more difficult to prove to UL and suchlike that your central region is properly symmetrically isolated than it would be with one gap. How can you ensure with future board revisions (possibly by other people) that the proper isolation will be maintained?